# How to create semi-transparent Windows form like Microsoft Office 2010 TP?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, aero

I need to create Windows form that has the following features.

1. Semi-transparent on top-half of form(about 100-200 pixel).
2. Quick access toolbar like Microsoft Office 2010 TP.
3. Control box(minimize, maximize, close button) that is generated by
   Windows API(I don't like to create custom control box).

[alt text http://rabu4g.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pkkJL5_Xgghjczn0wckj0lpDrPXL4EhIzUX9d5FyWXI5Pqoe8bz9F9y1agq18jEb5bSiK3anmEyiq7bfkhqju-dilWu_GgHCt/Capture.PNG](http://rabu4g.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pkkJL5_Xgghjczn0wckj0lpDrPXL4EhIzUX9d5FyWXI5Pqoe8bz9F9y1agq18jEb5bSiK3anmEyiq7bfkhqju-dilWu_GgHCt/Capture.PNG)

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of third-party controls that can provide the toolbar in the title bar - I like [DevExpress' offering](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Bars/) - but I'm unsure of the semi-transparent aspect.

Comment: It isn't free. I found some projects on CodeProject website about custom control on title bar and it's free. This question has been solved.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that "free" was a requirement.